# Wrapping JLabels inside a JPanel thats inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlabel

My Java is a bit rusty so please bear with me. I have a method in my GUI class that calls another class file which returns a JList. The problem im having is getting the text from the JList, you can see an example of the output below

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JList;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
 import com.example.tests.IJ_runTestAFJ;
 public class GUI_v2 extends JFrame
 {  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
IJ_CommonSetup setup = new IJ_CommonSetup();


Container c;
JPanel panel;
JScrollPane userScrollPane, errorScrollPane, sysScrollPane;
JTextArea   tfUserError, tfSysError;

private JButton resetButton;
public  JList<String> errorList;


GUI_v2() 
{
    resetButton = new JButton();
    resetButton.setText("Click to populate TextArea");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                //test.runTest_Login(stUserName,stPwd);
                updatePanel();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    panel = new JPanel();

    tfSysError = new JTextArea(10,33);
    tfSysError.setLineWrap(true);
    tfSysError.setEditable(false);
    tfSysError.setWrapStyleWord(false);
    sysScrollPane = new JScrollPane(tfSysError);
    sysScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    panel.add(sysScrollPane);
    panel.add(resetButton);

    c = getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,250); //width, height
    setLocation(600,0);
    setResizable(false);
    validate();     
}//close GUI

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new GUI_v2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public void updatePanel()
{       
    errorList = new JList<String>();
    errorList = setup.getErrorJList();
    tfSysError.append(errorList.getComponent(1).toString());
    validate();
}


}// end on class
```

IJ_CommonSetup.java

```
package com.example.tests;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
public class IJ_CommonSetup{
/**
 * 
 */

public static String stError = new String();
public static JList<String> stJListError = new JList<String>();


public JList<String> getErrorJList(){
    String error1 = new String("TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest ");
    String error2 = new String("ApplesApplesApplesApplesApplesApplesApplesApplesApplesApples ");
    JLabel newError1 = new JLabel();
    newError1.setText(error1);
    JLabel newError2 = new JLabel(error2);
    stJListError.add(newError1);
    stJListError.add(newError2);
            return stJListError;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Why not use a `JList` instead?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  It should take no more than 50 LOC (as opposed to > 300 LOC). 3) `label.setPreferredSize(..`  See See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> im having some trouble getting labels to wrap inside a panel that's
>   inside a Scrollpane. At the moment if the string thats added to the
>   label is long it is aligned to the left which is fine but the label
>   stretches outside the panel cutting off the end of the string.

- use `JTextArea(int, int)` in `JScrollPane`
- `setEditable(false)` for `JTextArea`

instead of `JLabel`s added to `JPanel` (in `JScrollPane`)

Answer (score 1):

Normal text in a JLabel doesn't wrap. You can try using HTML:

```
String text = "<html>long text here</html";
```